# Will these os.popen commands run in parallel?

Tags: python, python-2.7, popen

If I run a series of `os.popen(...)` statements in a loop, with a `read()` attached to each one, will the commands run in parallel, or will the `read()` calls cause the code to wait until each process has terminated before continuing?

```
for cmd in ['cmd1', 'cmd2', 'cmd3']:
    os.popen(cmd).read()
```

From reading the documentation I thought that the commands would run concurrently, however I tried an experiment launching a series of `sleep 1` commands in a loop like this:

```
for cmd in ['sleep 1', 'sleep 1', 'sleep 1']:
    os.popen(cmd).read()
```

and was expecting them to run concurrently but instead `popen` appeared to wait until each sleep command has finished before continuing with the next, so now I'm not sure.

I'm aware that `os.popen` is deprecated and that the `subprocess` module should be used instead, however I'm investigating a bug in a legacy script that uses `os.popen` and want to check if parallel execution of the commands could occur.

Comment: @OferSadan I tried the loop with sleeps again without the read() call and it still seems to wait for each one to complete

Comment: I think what you need is [`os.popen2`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/os.html#os.popen2)

Answer (score 0):

## UPDATE

The `read()` in your case fails because `['cm1', 'cmd2', 'cmd3']` are not valid commands. Even on the debugger if you pause and try to execute `os.popen(cmd).read()` it will be evaluating forever. It was a nice thought to run a `time.sleep()` but not in the for loop because this way you won't get the result needed. A valid test would be to run a `'sleep'` in console and since `TIMEOUT` from `popen()` redirects the input and fails we can use an example as the above:

```
import os
import time
for cmd in ['ping -n 3 127.0.0.1', 'ping -n 5 127.0.0.1', 'tree']:
    print(time.time())
    print(os.popen(cmd).readline())
```

In this case the first command will have a delay of 10 seconds and we can see that the processes do not run simultaneously, while one waits for the other to finish.
Here are the results and the times every process ran:

**1571386961.499955**

```
Pinging 127.0.0.1 with 32 bytes of data:
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.

Ping statistics for 127.0.0.1:
    Packets: Sent = 3, Received = 0, Lost = 3 (100% loss),
```

**1571386975.433736**

```
Pinging 127.0.0.1 with 32 bytes of data:
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.

Ping statistics for 127.0.0.1:
    Packets: Sent = 5, Received = 0, Lost = 5 (100% loss),
```

**1571386999.4259672**

```
Folder PATH listing
Volume serial number is EAE9-D593
C:.
ΓΔΔΔ.idea
³   ΓΔΔΔdictionaries
³   ΐΔΔΔinspectionProfiles
ΓΔΔΔarch_import_ops
```

Comment: sorry if I wasn't clear - I wasn't actually running the commands stated, they are just examples. I am happy that the commands I am using are valid when run

Comment: why are you using `readline`? and why do you think there should be a delay of 10 seconds?

Comment: I'm not clear why you say `sleep` isn't a valid test but `ping` is valid? Both commands take a few seconds to complete, what is the difference? edit - I think I understand the confusion, have edited the question

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga 10 seconds was an estimation because it will ping 10 times, either way it needs some time to finish this process so it would be clear if the process waits to be executed. Also I used `readline()` so it won't print too many, especially the `tree` command.

Comment: @codebox `time.sleep()` would run in python so it would stop and wait for the next process in the loop. If we run a cmd command that has a delay and takes some time to return we can recognize if the processes run simultaneously or one waits for the other to finish.

Comment: @KostasCharitidis sorry if I wasn't clear - see edit to question

Comment: @codebox yeap I made a mistake too. Seems that `readline()` was executing fast so I didn't see the difference. I tried with `read()` and the conclusion is that they do not run concurrently. One process exits and then the other starts

Comment: @KostasCharitidis I think the behaviour change change depending on the operating system, I ran my code on a linux box and saw 2 sleep commands running in parallel, on macOs they ran 1 at a time

Comment: @codebox well I am speaking from a windows perspective

Comment: I guess because it's the 'os' module it's not surprising there are differences